# Setting response on Jetty Server

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

One of the external application is calling a Jetty Server that I own.
They are using HttpPost to send the request.
But however the request does pass sometimes and sometimes jetty sends a

```
*************STATUS: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request********
*************STATUS CODE: 400********
```

Is there a way I can catch this and modify the response rather than jetty sending it automatically.

Currently in doGet method I always set the ServletResponse to OK.

Also does having a System.out.prinln in the doGet method result in exception or close the jetty server???

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost is likely [a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/775715), aka the [`doPost(request,response)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method, not the [`doGet(request,response)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method.

Using `System.out.println()` makes no difference to the HTTP processing.